# How to install npm modules on host machine using docker

Tags: node.js, docker

I have nodejs project with a `package.json` inside the folder.
I do not want to install nodejs on my host machine to just to run 'npm install'.
I want to use docker to do the `npm install` for me and destroy the container after.

I have done something similar for a php laravel project  like the command below

`docker run --rm -v /myapp:/app composer install`

The command above installed composer dependencies for my Laravel app and destroyed the container after.

Can I do the same for `npm install` with 1 line?.

Comment: Why don't you want to install Node?  On a MacOS host, at least, running `brew install node; npm install` is fewer characters than any correct Docker invocation.

Comment: I am on windows. The reason why i dont want to install it on my host is because it is not a 1 time thing. I use nodejs and different versions all the time. So i dont want my host getting messy . And i dont want to install something and leavve it there and never use it . so ya.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it: `docker run --rm -v $PWD:/app -w /app node npm install`

Comment: On windows powershell it would be `docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/app -w /app node npm install`